# Understanding a step in normal distribution function derivation

Tags: integration, statistics, derivatives, proof-explanation

I am a HS student with minimal knowledge of statistics and calculus (Calculus 1 level) . Could someone explain in detail what happens in between these two steps in this proof:https://web.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/papers/Normal/default.html
[image]

Comment: How much do you know about antiderivatives/integrals?  If the answer is 'nothing', then there is quite a bit of background you would need before understanding this.  If the answer is 'some', it would be helpful to include some idea of what you already know in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They integrated it.

In general,

$$\int \frac 1 x dx=ln |x| + c$$

and

$$\int x dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$

but if you have something like $x-\mu$, you do a u-substitution. Let $u=x-\mu$, then $du=dx$ and

$$\begin{split}\int (x-\mu)dx&=\int udu\\
&=\frac{u^2}{2}+c\\
&=\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+c\end{split}$$

Now you can see the step they took was:

$$\begin{split}\int \frac{df}{f}&=-k\int (x-\mu)dx\\
\ln|f|+\ln c_1&=-k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+\ln c_2\end{split}$$

Now you know that $\log a-\log b=\log \frac a b$. Thus

$$\begin{split}\ln|f|&=-k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+\ln c_2-\ln c_1\\
&=-k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+\ln \frac{c_2}{c_1}\\
&=-k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+\ln C\end{split}$$

with $C=\frac {c_1}{c_2}$. But since $c_1,c_2$ were arbitrary, C is as well.

Answer (score 1):

As indefinite integrals

- $\int \frac1{f} \, df = \ln(f)+A$ for some constant $A$
- $-k\int (x-\mu) \, dx = -k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+B$ for some constant $B$

If you let these be equal, you get  $\ln(f)+A = -k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+B$.  Now let $C=\exp(B-A)$, i.e. $\ln(C)=B-A$, you can rewrite this as $$\ln(f) = -k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}+\ln(C)$$ for some constant $C>0$.  You can go further and rewrite this as $$f=C\exp\left(-k\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2} \right)$$ which is starting to look related to the density function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac1k$.